# installing the boot loader in a separate pendrive

Tags: grub2, usb-drive, bootloader

I want to install Ubuntu 14.04 desktop in a PC in which there is two hard drives: one 1TB and the other is 80GB.

Windows 7 is Installed in the 1TB HD so I am not going to touch it and install Ubuntu in the 80Gb HD.

*My Question is*:

Could I install Ubuntu in that ​80GB HD and install the boot loader alone in a pendrive so that the system will automatically boot to windows when that pendrive is not connected.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, you can. You need to have your pen drive plugged in during the installation of Ubuntu and you need to tell Ubuntu that you want to place the boot loader on this pen drive. Assuming that you have two hard drives `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` the device for keeping new bootloader is `/dev/sdc`, which should be your pen drive.

To load Windows in your case you will need to select USB boot option in your BIOS. It is also needed to set Windows as default in GRUB menu configuration.

Be aware, that without this pen drive you will not be able to run Ubuntu although you will have it installed on one of the drive. This is because you are going to keep new bootloader on a pendrive. So in the scenario you asked in the question the MBR existing on one of the drives is not going to be changed.

So you will be able to load Windows only without pen drive or both Windows and Ubuntu with pen drive plugged in. Is there any sense to have such a setup or you need anything else?

Comment: I know it doesn't make sense for normal cases but the problem with me is that The system I'm going to install belongs to my brother, he didn't allow me to install Ubuntu at first then I managed to get his permission by saying that " I would make sure that you are not annoyed by the boot loader screen" therefore I came up with a idea like this. If there is any better way than this please suggest me.....

Comment: It has a sense then, from this point it sounds like a normal way you have chosen. So if the described method is clean for you then go for this.